# web based profiler for haskell

Tags: haskell

I vaguely remember seeing on a reddit a few months ago about a locally hosted web based profiler for haskell applications i.e. the profiler starts a local webpage and gives profiling information of the haskell code there. Does this still exist? I can't find the blog i originally saw it, or the actually profiler any where. I do not remember the original name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably thinking of the [EKG](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ekg) package.

Was it [this](http://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2012-12-11-24-day-of-hackage-ekg.html) blog post?